# After user click on like button page should not refresh (redirect) and update count of likes

Tags: python, django

When user click to like a post the web page should not refresh (redirect) and count of the likes should be updated. How can I achieve this please help me.

Here is my block of code

```
<a style="{% if request.session.email %}pointer-events: auto;{% else %}pointer-events: none;{% endif %}"
    href="/post_comment_like/{{j.id}}">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"
                                       style="color: gray;"></i></a>
```

`Views.py`:

```
def post_comment_like(request, id):
    if (request.session.get('email') is None) or (request.session.get('email') == ""):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/home")

    email = request.session.get('email')
    query = Comment.objects.get(id=id)
    obj_id = query.object_id
    query_like = Comment_like.objects.filter(email=email)
    query_like = Comment_like.objects.filter(email=email, object_id=query.id, dislike_comment="1").first()
    if query_like:
        query_like.delete()
    save_form = Comment_like(email=email, user_name=request.session.get('name'),
                                content_type=query.content_type,
                                object_id=query.id,
                                content=query.content,
                                flag_reply=query.flag_reply,
                                flag_comment_id=query.flag_comment_id,
                                flag_level=query.flag_level,
                                like_comment='1')
    save_form.save()
    query.like_comment = '1'
    query.dislike_comment = '0'
    query.save()

    # return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', args=[str(obj_id)]))
```

Comment: Post your js snippet too..

Answer (score 2):

As far as updating the number of likes on a page, this is about javascript with ajax requests.

1. for example if someone liked a post on the frontend, the moment the user clicked the like button there should be event listener that sends ajax request to the endpoint, something like this

```
fetch('https://example/api/posts/{post_id}/likes', {
methods:'POST',
body : JSON.stringify(data),
})
```

2. The endpoint on your code on django should receive the request and increase the number of like on the database
3. The frontend (javascript code) finally should send again another ajax request to get the number of the updated likes

```
fetch('https://example/api/posts/{post_id}/likes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to add one like in a separate view

Comment: Using ajax we can stop refreshing but at the same time I want to update comment count  and show in same web page. how to achieve this please help me out. Thank you

Comment: Just use javascript to update the UI and ajax for updating the database